# Create a template function that adds the elements of and array if different data types

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create a template function in C++ that return the sum of the elements of an array of different data types. I am having issues when I try to get my result. I  print out an address in memory (I guess). This is for my last homework in C++, so please some help in here ;-)
this is what I have so far:

```
template <class T>
int sum(T array, int size)
{
  int i;
  int result;
  for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    result += array[i];

} 

  return result; 
}
```

and my main() looks like

```
int main()
    {
    cout << "Printing Array sum..." << endl;
    len = sizeof(intArr) / sizeof(int);
    //len = sizeof(strArr) / sizeof(int);

    cout << sum(intArr, len)<<endl;
    //cout << sum(strArr, len)<<;



    return 0;
    }
```

my output in the command line is a random number 
Please a hint or help in how to solve this

Comment: shouldn't the result be of type T ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize `result` in `sum`, so it contains stack garbage. Then you add everything in `array` to stack garbage, which gives you garbage.

Comment: Awesome! thank you very much It worked flawlessly!